# How to Disable input field when radio button will choose using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I need one help.I need to disable some of my input field when radio button will select.Let me to explain my code below.

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
<span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">Unit Cost Price :</span>
<input type="text" name="discount" id="ucp" class="form-control" placeholder="Add unit cost price" ng-model="unit_cost_price" ng-keypress="clearField('ucp');" ng-readonly="ucpread" ng-disabled="ucpdis">
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12" >
<input type="radio" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="isChecked.new">Add new stock
<input type="radio" name="favoriteColors" ng-model="isChecked.old">Update stock 
</div>
```

In the above code i am getting `Update stock` is by default selected.I need when user will choose `Update stock` the above `Unit Cost Price` field will be disabled/readonly when user will choose `Add new stock` it will be enable.Please help me.

Comment: try `ng-disabled="isChecked.new"`

Comment: I tested but its not coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give value to radio button and compare it to disable\enable text

```
 <input type="radio" ng-model="isChecked" name="favoriteColors" value="true" />Add new stock
 <input type="radio" ng-model="isChecked" name="favoriteColors" value="false" />Update stock

 <input type="text" ng-disabled="isChecked=='false'">
```

Check this fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/ryf2h49p/